# How to dynamically make multiple Labels, Edits and etc. in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, list, controls, delphi-2009

I want users to create their own list of controls such as `TEdit`, `TCheckBox`, `TLabel`, and other things. But how can I make another, when I have to predefine every control, but I don't know how many objects to define?

Comment: @David Heffernan, note, that `TObjectList<T>` had a lot of issues in Delphi 2009 (partially resolved by hotfixes).

Comment: @TLama - is that a preemptive comment? I don't see David's comment or answer anywhere.

Comment: @TLama - did generics exist in D2009?

Comment: @Leonardo, yes, and yes :-)

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. You just write `MyEdit := TEdit.Create(Self)` and hey presto, runtime created edit control. Which part of all this are you struggling with?

Comment: I'm going to take the liberty of editing this question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should do to create each object knowing its class type:

```
var
  Obj:TControl;
begin
  Obj := TEdit.Create(AOwner);
  with Obj do begin
    //Set properties here...
    ...
    Parent := Self;    //Assuming that you're writing code in your form class. if not, use object variable pointing to your form instead of `self`
  end;
end;
```

To store unknown number of objects, you can either use a dynamic array, or link list, or you can even use the `Controls` property of the form.

This is the start of what you want to do (basics). You have plenty choices for implementing this part of your application. For example, you can have an `array of TControl` in your form class, and using `Length` and `SetLength` functions you can figure out how many objects your user has added to the form.

Comment: Wouldn't `with TEdit.Create(AOwner) do begin...` also work? Not in front of IDE at the moment...

Comment: @Jerry: Sure, but we won't have a pointer to our object which might be necessary.